# Regex pattern match performance in Java for long string

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex that works great(500 nanoseconds) when a match is found, but takes a lot of time (over 3 secs) when there is no match. I suspect this could be because of backtracking. I tried some options, like converting `.*` to `(.*)?` based on some documentation, but it didn't help.

Input: a very long string - 5k chars in some cases.

Regex to match: `.*substring1.*substring2.*`

I am pre-compiling the pattern and re-using the matcher, what else can I try?

Here's my code snippet - I will be calling this method with millions of different input strings, but just a handful of regex patterns.

```
private static HashMap<String, Pattern> patternMap = new HashMap<String, Pattern>();
private static HashMap<String, Matcher> matcherMap = new HashMap<String, Matcher>();
```

Here's my method:

```
public static Boolean regex_match(String line, String regex) {
    if (regex == null || line == null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (!patternMap.containsKey(regex)) {
      patternMap.put(regex, Pattern.compile(regex));
      matcherMap.put(regex,patternMap.get(regex).matcher(""));
    }
    return matcherMap.get(regex).reset(line).find(0);
 }
```

Comment: What is your goal here? Do you need to use regex?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: @Pshemo - yes, I do have to use regex.

Comment: Is there a reason that you need .* before and after? It should be much faster if you use find() instead of match() and get rid of the .* prefix and suffix on your expression.

Comment: Do you have these patterns hardcoded or do you build them dynamically? I can suggest using unrolled patterns like [`substring1[^s]*(?:s(?!ubstring2)[^s]*)*substring2`](https://regex101.com/r/fW5jH1/1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is subject to a problem known as catastrophic backtracking, as you hinted at. Essentially, the first `.*` will match the entire string, and then backtrack until `substring1` matches. This will repeat with `substring2`. Because `substring2` fails, the second `.*` will need to find another place where `substring2` begins to match, and then it will fail again. Each time `substring1` matches, we need to check every single place that `substring2` might match.

You already are using `pattern.find()`, so you can omit the starting and ending `.*`. Then, changing the inner `.*` to a `.*?` could improve the performance by turning the greedy matcher into a lazy one.

This produces: `substring1.*?substring2`

Comment: Perfect. This is way more performant than the regex that I had. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can verify that the pattern will match if you use `indexOf()`:

```
int pos1 = str.indexOf("substring1");
int pos2 = str.indexOf("substring2", pos1);

if(pos1 != -1 && pos2 != -1){
  // regex
}
```

---

When the regex doesn't match, you will get catastrophic backtracking. In fact, your pattern is likely doing a lot of backtracking even when there is a match. The `.*` will eat up the entire string, and then needs to go backwards, reluctantly giving back characters.

If your string looks like: `substring1 substring2........50000 more characters......`, then you will get better performance with the lazy `.*?`. Please note that `(.*)?` is NOT the same as `.*?`.

The performance of the regex will vary depending on what the substrings are, and what they're matched against. If your string looks like: `substring1........50000 more characters...... substring2`, then you will get better performance with the `.*` that you have.

Answer (score 1):

Using `String.indexOf()` is much faster than Regex if the case is simple enough you can use it. You could recode your problem as:

```
public static boolean containsStrings(String source, String string1, String string2) {
  long pos1, pos2;
  pos1 = source.indexOf(string1);
  if(pos1 > -1) {
    pos2 = source.indexOf(string2,pos1 + string1.length);
    if(pos2 > pos1 && source.indexOf(string1,pos2 + string2.length) < -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Note that my solution does not deal with the case where `string2` is contained in `string1`, if that is the case you'll need to add that to the logic.

Comment: The idea is good, but this will fail if there are two occurrences of `string2`, one before and one after `string1`. Better find `string1` first and then use its index as start index for the search for `string2`

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work as my function should be able to handle any regex. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @user100001 Too bad, in a real life case with 20mb of text I used `indexOf()` and `contains()` as much as possible and regex only for the complex cases. The performance gain from using regex sparingly on large documents was several orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

`^((?!substring1).)*substring1((?!substring2).)*substring2.*?\Z`

Should do it because a string that contains one substring multiple times but not both in order won't backtrack ad nauseam.  You can drop the .*?\Z at the end if you don't need the matcher to end at end of input.